# Error!: Duplicate definition for 'javax.bluetooth.BluetoothConnectionException'

Tags: java, windows, blackberry, multiplatform, bluecove

I have seen a similar problem [here for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976763/blackberry-problem-using-java-se-features) , but i am not trying to acces to Java SE features..

I have a .jar file with the code of a bluetooth functionality.. I try to make a .jar package that works with Blackberry and Windows.. In both cases i use the `javax.bluetooth.BluetoothConnectionException` class. This class comes in the Blackberry SDK and in the BlueCove package to use Bluetooth in Windows... so the BlueCove package is included in the jar file..

When i try to use the .jar file with the Blackberry, i have the error mentioned in the title: `Error!: Duplicate definition for 'javax.bluetooth.BluetoothConnectionException'`.. My problem here is that i want to use a feature that comes in the Standard SDK from RIM, but there is another class with the same name and in the same package in the .jar file, and therefore, i get this error... **Is there some way to make the BlackBerry application to look for this class in its own SDK instead of the .jar file?**

I think that i cannot / should not modify the package of any of the classes. **Any ideas here?** I would appreciate any.

Thanks

PS: I use the Eclipse plug-in for Blackberrry, in case that is usefull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would get the source code of BlueCove project, and open it in a IDE, for example Netbeans, and refactor package names. Change (refactor) package names to avoid name conflict.

After that include refactored BlueCove sources or compiled jar file to your BlackBerry project.

Comment: Do you think i will be able to do it? I am trying it, and so far, i had to download the BlueCove source code, the javax.jms, the org.apache, javaMail... and have still missing packages...

Comment: Source code is [available for download](http://code.google.com/p/bluecove/). And there are "build" bat files inside of downloaded archive. If build does not work, post a question to [BlueCove users](http://groups.google.com/group/bluecove-users/?pli=1) usergroup.

Comment: Ok @Rafael. Thank you very much.. I think i was doing something wrong, because i had compilation errors... But now everything seems to work.. I will try the new package with the blackberry program, but i think this shold have to work...